# When should I optimize OpenGL ES shaders for older mobile devices using 1D lookup tables?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I am trying to optimize shader speed for older devices across Android and iOS. Obviously I could test this on single devices, but I am more interested in general performance for my game across all platforms. I have two functions that are used to get an estimated value in a spectrum based on a percent.

```
float wave(float pos)
{
    float frac = mod(pos, 1.0);  
    float val1 = mod(floor(pos), 6.0);
    float val2 = mod(val1 + 1.0, 6.0);

    return floor(val1 / 3.0) * (1.0 - frac) + floor(val2 / 3.0) * frac;
}

vec3 spectrum(float percent)
{
    float wave_pos = percent * 6.;
    float r = wave(wave_pos);
    float g = wave(wave_pos + 2.);
    float b = wave(wave_pos + 4.);
    return vec3(r,g,b);
}
```

I was considering replacing this with a 1D lookup texture. This would handle the linear interpolation as well. I know that random location texture lookup is not always optimized on old devices. As you can see, it would replace about 18 built in function calls as well as 13 multiplications.  Is this generally considered good practice?

Comment: *"Is this generally considered good practice?"* This question can't be answered by yes or no. The precision of the computation in the shader is limited (precision qualifiers). The lookup is an approximation. My advice is, try it. Compare the result and measure the time.

Comment: Yes, but to my point above, there are 1000's of Android devices from many different manufacturers. I can get good profiling on a few, but that is why I was looking for general practice. Would this be considered an optimization or a slowdown. I will certainly test though on some of my older devices though.

Comment: Probably, it depends on if the entire texture can be take loaded into the cache, but that's just a guess. Anyway a noise texture is common.